# Why are Java class files "typically (but not necessarily)" stored in a file?

Tags: java, class, jvm

Based on documentation:

> Compiled code to be executed by the Java virtual machine is represented using a hardware- and operating system-independent binary format, typically (but not necessarily) stored in a file, known as the class file format.

How understand this line:   `typically (but not necessarily)` . What does it mean? I can save in something like `my file` or `hello file`, or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that compiled classes are usually stored in files, but in some systems they might be stored some other way (not in a file).

For example, with the Oracle database it is possible to write stored procedures in Java. These stored procedures will be compiled, but not saved in a class file; instead, the compiled class is stored in the database somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is a description. the classloader can be configured to read classes from any stream. So if it's an applet.. it would be a network stream, not a file

Answer (score 1):

It could be compiled directly to and executed from memory, for example.

Answer (score 1):

The "typically (but not necessarily)" qualification just means that compiled code does not *have* to be stored in a file, though it *usually* will be. For example: a Java class could be compiled to, stored in, and executed solely in memory.

Answer (score 1):

It could live in a database, not a file. (Oracle does that.) Or, for a really slow JVM, be tattooed on the leg of a hipster.

But it's usually in a file ending with .class, perhaps zipped up into a jar.

Answer (score 0):

The code could be in memory instead of file. It would be there eventually, after the interpreter loads it from the file.